# String comparator as a lambda

Tags: java, performance, sorting, comparative-review, lambda

I am writing a Comparator for my TreeMap. It looks like this:

```
private static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR = 
new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int cmp = o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());
        if (cmp != 0) return cmp;

        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};
```

My IDE hints me that it could be written in a lambda. I came up with this idea:

```
private static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR_LAMBDA = 
(s1, s2) -> 
s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase()) == 0 ? 
s1.compareTo(s2) : s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
```

But then I am duplicating the first call `s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase()`. This is doing two  String manipulation and one comparison more than the not lambda expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also chain the `Comparator`s using `thenComparing`

```
CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparing((Function<String, String>) String::toLowerCase)
                                        .thenComparing(o -> o);
```

Official Java docs on [thenComparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a modification of [@Ankint Soni](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/171855/ankit-soni) solution with less structural diversity:

```
CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR = Comparator.<String, String>comparing(o -> o.toLowerCase()).thenComparing(o -> o);
```

Or a slightly different flavor, more expressive:

```
CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR = Comparator.<String, String>comparing(o -> o.toLowerCase()).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Comment: Second example: Do you mean more expensive in the performance?

Comment: The why do you show me this?))

Comment: If you have performance problems at this point you have a general performance problem.

Answer (score 2):

Even in the lambda, the RHS can be a code block with braces.

```
private static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR_LAMBDA = 
(s1, s2) -> {
    int cmp = o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());
    if (cmp != 0) return cmp;

    return o1.compareTo(o2);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What is a RHS?

Comment: Right hand side :)